# Drupal Field Hierarchy or Fields By Selection

Tags: entities

Is there any modules that support a hierarchy for fields?  Nodes and fieldable entities in drupal seem so monolithic.  For example customers could be categorized into three categories:

Customer A
Customer B
Customer C

When customer A is selected then I only want specific fields shown according to that selection, and would be different for B and C.

I know I can do this via a hook_form_alter using the ajax callback attribute but wasn't sure if there was something already created for this.  I seen the hierarchy module but seems to be specific towards taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module could provide a solution for you.

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7), plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on certain conditions when viewing content.